# How to use first() with a function where column has null values and group it by another column in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by

i have a DF where I want to calculate the first possible value as a chr() in column "A" (which is not null) and add the result to a new column "C" grouped by column "Date".
(As an information chr(97)=a)

The result should look something like that:

```
+----------+----------+---+---+
|Date      |A         |B  |C  |
+----------+----------+---+---+
|21.02.2022|null      |12  |a  |
|21.02.2022|null      |23  |a  |
|21.02.2022|97        |25  |a  |
|22.02.2022|98        |28  |b  |
|22.02.2022|120       |29  |b  |
|22.02.2022|121       |19  |b  |
|22.02.2022|null      |10  |b  |
+----------+----------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "first possible value" you mean the lowest value per Date. Otherwise your problem is not well defined, because Spark does not preserve there ordering of the rows in a data frame unless `sort()` or `.orderBy()` is called.

If the assumption is correct you could solve it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
(
    df
    .withColumn('C', F.first('A', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy('Date').orderBy('A')))
    .withColumn('C', F.chr('C'))
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Yes your assumption is correct. Your code is partially working but if i try to use the code i get a TypeError: an integer is required (got type str).  I think it has something to do with the last part of the code: ".withColumn('C', F.chr('C'))". I dont know why it doesnt work. Column "C" has only integer values...

Comment: I am not really familiar with F.chr(). It might be that you have to put F.chr(F.col(„C“)) - cannot test it myself right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collect_list` windowing function partitioned by `Date` to get an array of A values.